# two questions about content-type

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

New to XMLHttpRequest, and here is some confusion for me:

1. Why must we set the content type when using the post method in a xmlhttprequest?

   XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
2. Isnt the default value application/x-www-form-urlencoded already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why must we set the content type when using the post method in a xmlhttprequest?

```
XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

HTTP/POST does not ask for that specific content-type when you do a HTTP/POST over AJAX (or for that matter via other means). It is up to you (and up to the server side program handling it). Read the second section for Why we must set it explicitly.

Very often, we serialise the form (percentile-encode it -- a=b&c=d format) and send it across to the server. This format is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you are sending an XML, you would use `application/xml`, for JSON you would use `application/json` and so on.

As for GET request, there's no body and hence we dont really need the content-type header.

> Isnt the default value application/x-www-form-urlencoded already?

I tried skimming through [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) for the default content-type header. I couldn't find anything. However, when I tried doing a HTTP/POST AJAX request via chrome's console, I noticed that chrome's default is `application/xml`.

Just a piece of advice -- never rely on default behaviour except when its explicitly stated and/or is a part of the standard. Why not set the content type explicitly?

Comment: Thanks dude. Your answer helped me understand MIME/content types. My second question was because im lazy and I didnt look at it like from your point of view. Seeing now, that chrome uses application/xaml is a real eye opener for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is also one tool which help you for passing parameters via application/x-www-form-urlencoded. https://www.browserling.com/tools/url-encode. Also i suggest you to use Postman tool first to check the API response and then use Ajax call in JS